# Upgrade path from Integrated Dynamic Placeholders to Sitecore 9 Dynamic Placeholders (OOTB)

Tags: presentation, mvc, powershell-extensions, upgrade

Does anyone have a SPE script that could be used to upgrade the rendering parameters of existing content to the new dynamic placeholder style required for Sitecore 9 Dynamic placeholders?

We used to use:
Placeholder
Placeholder_1
Placeholder_2
etc...

Now required:
Placeholder-{parent_rendering_guid}-0
Placeholder-{parent_rendering_guid}-1

The tricky part is getting that parent rendering guid to update the placeholder value with.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Here are two PowerShell scripts that we successfully ran to fulfill this task. The first creates a CSV file with all items that have dynamic placeholders. The second loops through the rows in the CSV and updates the dynamic placeholder rendering parameters.

Script 1:

- Update the 'Home' node path and the 'basePageTemplateId' Guid

Write-Output "Start Script " (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')

$elevatedUser= Get-User -Identity "sitecore\admin"
New-UsingBlock (New-Object Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher $elevatedUser) {

```
    $database = "master" #master|web
    $startPath = "$($database):/sitecore/content/Home"
    $placeholderKey = "/main/*"

    $basePageTemplateId = [Sitecore.Data.ID]::Parse("{54BD9D21-90F2-4D22-A0BF-8747DD7C23B4}")

    $itemsWithPlaceholders = @()

    Get-ChildItem -Path $startPath -Language * -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
        $item = $_;
        $doesItInherit = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.TemplateManager]::GetTemplate($_.TemplateID, $_.Database).InheritsFrom($basePageTemplateId)

        #Write-Output "Outer Id: " $_.Id

        if($doesItInherit) {
            $renderings = Get-Rendering -Item $_  -Placeholder $placeholderKey -FinalLayout:$True
            foreach($rendering in $renderings){
                $matches = [regex]::Matches($rendering.Placeholder,'([0-9a-f]{8}[-][0-9a-f]{4}[-][0-9a-f]{4}[-][0-9a-f]{4}[-][0-9a-f]{12})$')
                if ($matches.Success) {

                    $itemWithPlaceholder = @{
                        Language = $_.Language
                        Version = $_.Version                        
                        ItemId = $_.Id
                    }
                    $itemsWithPlaceholders += New-Object PSObject -Property $itemWithPlaceholder

                    #Write-Output "Inner Id: " $_.Id
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $itemsWithPlaceholders | export-csv -Path C:\Temp\Items-With-Dynamic-Placeholders.csv -NoTypeInformation

    Write-Output "Done"
}
```

Script 2:

```
Write-Output "Start Script " (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt')

$csvPath = "C:\Temp\Items-With-Dynamic-Placeholders.csv"
$itemsWithDynamicPlaceholders = Import-Csv $csvPath

$placeholderKey = "/main/*"

foreach($row in $itemsWithDynamicPlaceholders) {

    Write-Host "Item details: " $row.ItemId ", " $row.Version ", " $row.Language

    $item = Get-Item -Path master: -ID $row.ItemId -Language $row.Language -Version $row.Version

    $renderings = Get-Rendering -Item $item -Placeholder $placeholderKey -FinalLayout:$True

    Write-Host $renderings.Count

    foreach($rendering in $renderings){

        $matches = [regex]::Matches($rendering.Placeholder,'([0-9a-f]{8}[-][0-9a-f]{4}[-][0-9a-f]{4}[-][0-9a-f]{4}[-][0-9a-f]{12})$')
        if ($matches.Success) {

            $renderingId = $matches.Groups[0].Value

            $newPlaceholder = $rendering.Placeholder.Replace($renderingId, "{$($renderingId.ToUpper())}-0")
            $newPlaceholder = $newPlaceholder.Replace("_", "-")
            $rendering.Placeholder = $newPlaceholder
            $Placeholder = $rendering.Placeholder
            try{

                #Write-Host "Update Attempt: "$item.Name ", " $renderingId ", " $Placeholder

                Set-Rendering -Item $item -Instance $rendering -FinalLayout:$True
            }
            catch{
                $counter = $counter + 1
                Write-Output (Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt') " Error ItemId: " $item.ID.Guid " Name:  " $item.Name " Placeholder: " $Placeholder " Language: "  $item.Language.Name 
            }

        }
    }
}

Write-Output "Done"
```

Comment: Reading through this code it seems this is for modules similar to the Fortis Dynamic Placeholders. In the placeholder it has the GUID so it's a matter of reformatting it. The Integrated Dynamic Placeholder module has /main/placeholder_SCEXP1 for instance - so the mapping of placeholder to parent rendering GUID has to be created